# Procedural to functional style

Tags: function-construction, iterators

The following code generates an iterative mapping of some trigonometric functions. I have a couple questions about it. The first question is how to optimize this iterative process using mathematica's language and the second is about the result. Do you think the flower looking structures that appear in these plots are a result of some numerical instability or a true part of the mathematics? Additionally, I was trying to get the different listplots to show up in different colors. thx

```
k = 100000;
m = 5;
For[l = 0, l <= m, l++,
  dt = .0001 + .0005 l; t = 0; x = RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}]; 
  y = RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}];
  xs = Table[0 , {n, 1, k}]; ys = Table[0 , {n, 1, k}];
  For[n = 1, n <= k, 
    n++, {xp = x, yp = y, x = Cos[4 yp] Cos[t], y = Sin[xp] Sin[t], 
     xs[[n]] = x, ys[[n]] = y, t = t + dt}]
   data = 
    Partition[Flatten[Table[{xs[[n]], ys[[n]]}, {n, 1, k}]], 2] // N;
  Subscript[p, l] = 
   ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Hue[l], PointSize[.001]}, AspectRatio -> 1]];
Art = Table[Subscript[p, n], {n, 0, m}];
Show[Art]
```

[image]

If you consider the frequency of the cosine term as a parameter $x_{n+1} = \cos(ay_n)\cos(t_n)$ a bifurcation occurs at approx. $a=2.939$.

Comment: `Subscript[p, l] = ListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> {ColorData[3, "ColorList"][[l]], PointSize[.001]},  AspectRatio -> 1]` shows http://i.stack.imgur.com/O3pjs.png

Comment: No, it's not numerical instability. Take a look at [Peter de Jong attractor](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/peterdejong/) which is created in similar manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
i = Module[{k = 100000, m = 5, data, dt, t},
       data = (dt = .0001 + .0005 #; t = -dt;
               NestList[{Cos[4 #[[2]]] Cos[t += dt], Sin[#[[1]]] Sin[t]} &, 
                        RandomReal[{0, 2 π}, 2], k]) & /@ Range[0, m];
       ListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, .5 {-1, 1}}, Axes->None,
                PlotStyle->({PointSize[.001], #}&/@ ColorData[17,"ColorList"])]
]
```

And then we go for some embellishments:

```
ColorNegate@ColorCombine[MeanShiftFilter[#, 5, .3] & /@ 
                         DeleteSmallComponents /@ ColorNegate /@ ColorSeparate[i]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

This is twice as fast:

```
r = Compile[{{k, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}}, 
   Module[{dt, t}, (dt = .0001 + .0005 #; t = -dt;
       NestList[{Cos[4 #[[2]]] Cos[t += dt], Sin[#[[1]]] Sin[t]} &, 
        RandomReal[{0, 2 π}, 2], k]) & /@ Range[0, m]]];
Module[{k = 100000, m = 5}, 
 ListPlot[r[k, m], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, .5 {-1, 1}}, 
  Axes -> None,   PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[.001], #} & /@ ColorData[22, "ColorList"])]]
```

Comment: @Kuba Quality takes time!

Comment: @Öskå I don't think I it's the case :) belisarius, don't you feel like `NestList` is kind of slow here?

Comment: @Kuba I didn't try to run it, I just liked the image :) But I like the images you linked in the [comment above](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48963/procedural-to-functional-style#comment146434_48963) even more. _GimmeTehCodez_!

Comment: @Öskå The same as here, it's even simpler because there is no equivalent of `dt`.

Comment: Are you implying that [this](http://paulbourke.net/fractals/peterdejong/roger1.jpg) is now easy?

Comment: @Öskå http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~phlosoft/attractors/

Comment: @Öskå That´s why it is called *quality* time.

Comment: Seems like the timing of the Module is about the same as the original code on my machine. Would a compile help here?

Comment: @Kuba Compiling shaves 50%

Comment: @belisarius Nice, I should start doing this :P

Comment: @Öskå At least it is not really hard to come up with a starting point: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TSupn.gif

Comment: @halirutan I like your "starting point" :D